# Nginx + PHP-FPM не пишут логи ошибок

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Связка Nginx (1.8.0) + PHP-FPM (5.6.16) не пишет логи ошибок. Файл ошибок вирт.хоста пустой, файл ошибок php-fpm не создается.

Нашел статью 2012 года ([тут](https://blog.ed.gs/2012/10/16/php-fpm-error-logging-to-nginx/)) в которой описывается эта проблема, сделал как там, результата не получил. Есть похожая [тема на ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/623640/how-does-php5-fpm-send-errors-to-nginx), но ответа там нет, только совет.

**php-fpm.conf**

> catch_workers_output = yes

**php.ini**

> log_errors = On
>
> error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log

**virt-host.conf**

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 8080;

    server_name domain.local;
}

server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    server_name domain.local;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/site/backend/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /usr/share/nginx/site/backend/log/access.log;
    error_log   /usr/share/nginx/site/backend/log/error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
   }

   location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
   }
}
```

**Итого:**

1. При ошибке 500 браузер сообщает о внутренней ошибке сервера
2. файл ошибок врит. хоста есть, но в него ничего не пишется (пустой)
3. файл лога вирт. хоста есть, в него все исправно пишется
4. файл ошибок php-fpm не создается после перезапуска демона

Собственно вопрос в том как же все-таки заставить php-fpm передавать информацию об ошибках в лог вирт. хоста nginx?

Comment: какие значения имеют display_errors, errors_reporting?

Comment: @Etki В php.ini display_errors=off  error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Comment: пните меня (с помощью такого же уведомления), если до выходных не появится ответа

Comment: Обнаружил еще странный момент. Рядом другой виртуалхост с таким же конфигом спокойно пишет лог ошибок. Права на запись в файлы логов у обоих одинаковые

Comment: @Etki Все так же нужна ваша помощь

Comment: боюсь, у меня сейчас очень плохо со временем

Comment: У меня сейчас тоже не пишет логи, пока не перезапущу nginx, как только очищу логи, все, больше не пишет до следующего рестарта. Так и с Apache2, но в Apache2 помогало в терминале echo '' > logs/error.log, а с nginx не прокатило